# Why using tf.transpose for transformer on my own data, made problems in model.fit function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, training-data, transformer-model

I want to do fine tuning for a transformer model, on my data. I based on [that](https://github.com/sayakpaul/TF-2.0-Hacks/blob/master/data2vec_vision_image_classification.ipynb) code but the difference, it is my data. I tried to load the data as tf.data.Dataset.from_generator, like explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)

Then by performing transform in this way:

```
def make_dataset(dataset: tf.data.Dataset, train: bool, image_size: int = IMAGE_SIZE):
def preprocess(image, label):
    # for training, do augmentation
    if train:
        if tf.random.uniform(shape=[]) > 0.5:
            image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, size=image_size, method="bicubic")
    return image, label

if train:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 10)

dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, AUTO).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
# Transpose because the `transformers` model has a leading channel dimension.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.transpose(x, [0, 3, 1, 2]), y), AUTO)**
return dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
```

I get the following error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2703355/4289617362.py in <module>
----> 1 train_dataset = make_dataset(train_dataset, True)
      2 val_dataset = make_dataset(val_dataset, False)

/tmp/ipykernel_2703355/2956852849.py in make_dataset(dataset, train, image_size)
     17     dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, AUTO).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
     18     # Transpose because the `transformers` model has a leading channel dimension.
---> 19     dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tf.transpose(x, [0, 3, 1, 2]), y), AUTO)
     20     return dataset.prefetch(AUTO)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, deterministic, name)
   2016       return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True, name=name)
   2017     else:
-> 2018       return ParallelMapDataset(
   2019           self,
   2020           map_func,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, num_parallel_calls, deterministic, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function, name)
   5232     self._input_dataset = input_dataset
   5233     self._use_inter_op_parallelism = use_inter_op_parallelism
-> 5234     self._map_func = structured_function.StructuredFunctionWrapper(
   5235         map_func,
   5236         self._transformation_name(),
...
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_2703355/2956852849.py", line 19, in None  *
        lambda x, y: (tf.transpose(x, [0, 3, 1, 2]), y)

    ValueError: Dimension must be 5 but is 4 for '{{node transpose}} = Transpose[T=DT_FLOAT, Tperm=DT_INT32](args_0, transpose/perm)' with input shapes: [?,32,224,224,3], [4].
```

I do not understand what that error is about. Who needs 5 dimensions, and how to fix it?

Edit:

The shape of data:

```
train_dataset.element_spec

    (TensorSpec(shape=(32, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(32, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

and:

```
val_dataset.element_spec
```

gave me the same.

[link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IhV06R7VTQ0nQ1gs4PqThrKo18lHShIC#scrollTo=Vz_kqZWrgykI) to my code

Comment: I also tried what you suggested. It works, but I got that error now in model.fit: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 3, 224, 224), found shape=(None, 32, 3, 224, 224).  Can you explain more about that dimensions?

Comment: `train_dataset.element_spec` should be (256, 256, 3) and not (32, 256, 256, 3). Remove the batch and pass it to `make_dataset`

Comment: Thanks @V.M:) Its a problem, cause it make an unclear error in model.fit() . I would be happy if you can take a look at my code. I added a link in my question.